# Cassandra repeated Error

Tags: cassandra

We have 48 Nodes Cassandra Cluster and we are getting a repeated error in only one node.Any idea what may be the reason. Error is as below :

```
ERROR [BatchlogTasks:1] 2023-08-29 09:12:55,524  CassandraDaemon.java:139 - Exception in thread Thread[BatchlogTasks:1,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.batchlog.BatchlogManager$ReplayingBatch.<init>(BatchlogManager.java:367)
        at org.apache.cassandra.batchlog.BatchlogManager.lambda$processBatchlogEntries$0(BatchlogManager.java:290)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.flow.Flow$ReduceSubscriber.onNext(Flow.java:1227)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.flow.Threads$SchedulingTransformer.lambda$onNext$0(Threads.java:326)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.TPCRunnable.run(TPCRunnable.java:101)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.IOScheduler$PooledTaskWorker.run(IOScheduler.java:319)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.InlinedThreadLocalThread.run(InlinedThreadLocalThread.java:251)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.IOThread.run(IOThread.java:46)
        Suppressed: org.apache.cassandra.utils.flow.Flow$FlowException: Flow call chain:
        PagerFlow
        SchedulingTransformerIO scheduler: cached workers: 7(IOScheduler.java:183)
        ReduceToSingle      org.apache.cassandra.batchlog.BatchlogManager$$Lambda$2231/914170156@7b2cb757(BatchlogManager.java:286)
                at org.apache.cassandra.utils.flow.Flow.wrapException(Flow.java:2683)
                at org.apache.cassandra.utils.flow.Flow$ReduceSubscriber.onError(Flow.java:1270)
                at org.apache.cassandra.utils.flow.Flow$ReduceSubscriber.onNext(Flow.java:1231)
                ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you running?

Comment: we had DSE 6.7.6 version recently upgraded to 6.8.14. This error is repeating in both versions